# Resampling time series with xts and zoo packages in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I am trying to resample a dataset with a given temporal resolution of 5 min ([source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nybqzujfn2oeis/SRI_2010.csv?dl=0)). In order to get a 30 min resampled temporal resolution I've tried:

```
#Date and Time together
SRI_2010$Date_Time = paste(SRI_2010$Date, SRI_2010$Time, sep=" ")
SRI_2010$Date_Time=as.character(SRI_2010$Date_Time)
SRI_2010$Date_Time=as.POSIXct(SRI_2010$Date_Time,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

#Creating the zoo object
SRI_2010.zoo <- zoo(SRI_2010,as.POSIXct(SRI_2010$Date_Time))

#Criteria for the resampling
ends2010 <- endpoints(SRI_2010.zoo,'minutes', 30)
SRI_30m_2010 <-period.apply(SRI_2010.zoo$SRI..W.m2.,ends2010,mean)
```

At the very beginning, I was quite satisfied because the code worked out,  but after a double-check, I've  realised it calculates the mean values at min 25 and 55, instead of at min 00 and 30 that I am interested in.

Example:

```
> SRI_30m_2010
2010-07-28 04:55:00 2010-07-28 05:25:00 
         3.80000000         12.06666667 
2010-07-28 05:55:00 2010-07-28 06:25:00 
        19.73333333         28.46666667 
2010-07-28 06:55:00 2010-07-28 07:25:00 
        40.30000000         61.60000000
```

This small issue is super annoying when I aim to combine different datasets with different temporal resolutions into a communal one.  Does anyone know how could I sort this issue out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" is that `endpoints` is doing what it was designed to do. It's returning the last timestamp of each period. I recommend you use `align.time` to move the index timestamp forward to the minutes you're interested in.

```
s <- align.time(as.xts(SRI_30m_2010), 60*30)
```

It's also not much of an issue if you're trying to combine multiple series with different resolutions into a single xts object. You could just merge them all, use `na.locf` or similar to fill in missing values, then extract the resolution you're interested in. I believe the xts FAQ shows you how to do this, and I know I've demonstrated it more than a couple times in my other answers on stackoverflow.